# Set TextField value after debounce not working

Tags: reactjs

Search field not working as expected after I set the value in TextField matirial ui. I want to be able to search for users in my list after 2000ms I done typing and if I click on one user to see the details and after that i go back, I want to be able to see again the input and for that I think I need to set the value at TextField.

The code below is working. Starts to search the input after 2000ms user stops typing, but when I came back, the input filed is empty, but I still have the specific users I searched for

```
  const handleDebouncedSearch = useCallback(
    debounce(getUsers, 2000),
    [],
  );
    

<TextField
          id="search"
          label={t('search')}
          onChange={(e) => {
            handleDebouncedSearch(e.target.value);
            console.log(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
```

but as soon I add value and start to type it fails. I can add only one letter and have to wait 2000ms in order to type another letter

```
const handleDebouncedSearch = useCallback(
        debounce(getProcessedCandidates, 2000),
        [],
      );
        

    <TextField
              id="search"
              label={t('search')}
              onChange={(e) => {
                handleDebouncedSearch(e.target.value);
                console.log(e.target.value);
              }}
              value={user.filter.searchQ}
            />
```

Also, if i console.log the "user.filter.serchQ" is the debounced value

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, what you're going to implement is firing search function after 2000ms. The problem here is that changing search value is debounced. You should have a function/method that changes search value and call debounced search function inside it.

Like this, for example:

```
const [searchValue, setValue] = useState(0)

const handleDebouncedSearch = (value) => {
    setValue(value)
    debounce(getProcessedCandidates, 2000)
};

const getProcessedCandidates = () => {
    // search goes here...
}

<TextField
              id="search"
              label={t('search')}
              onChange={(e) =>
                handleDebouncedSearch(e.target.value)
              }
              value={searchValue}
            />
```

HINT: You can also use useEffect and fire debounced search everytime searchValue changes.

Let me know if this is what you've expected.

Comment: This is not what I want.  The first code is working, but I need to save the value somehow

Comment: Then I recommend you to use redux

Comment: Do you want searchValue and search results to be saved even when user selects item from the list and navigates to another page? If so, search value and search results should be stored in redux store